# I have something bad in jquery submit

Tags: jquery

I try send form by jquery and no works me i put my code here , in this code i put the script in jquery and the html code i use for send this simple form :

**JQUERY SCRIPT**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var data = jQuery('#form1').serialize(); 
jQuery.ajax({
data: data,
cache: false,
url: '<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>',
type: 'POST',
async:false,  
success: function() 
{
jQuery("#okok").show(); 
};

});

});

</script>

HTML CODE

<div id="okok" style="display:none;"></div>


<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<p>
<input type="text" name="title" id="textfield" class="cp_input_asesor"/>
</p>


<input type="submit" name="button" class="cp_submit_asesor" value="Send" />
</p>
</form>
```

Thank´s , the best regards !!!

Comment: The way it is now, I do not think you will 'see' anything when you `show()` div `id='okok'` -- place some text inside that div.

Answer (score 1):

The code should fire the ajax request when the submit event is fired on the form.  Specify an event handler for the submit event on `#form1` the sends the ajax request.  Currently the ajax request will be set when the page is loaded and the form is most likely empty.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = jQuery('#form1').serialize(); 
        jQuery.ajax({
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            url: '<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>',
            type: 'POST',
            async:false,  
            success: function(){
               jQuery("#okok").show(); 
            }
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank´s but for example in this page i load i have the header and footer and other divs , because the form inside the same page , how i can show that div when load inside jquery all page other time when submit the form , thank´s

Comment: He has onsubmit="return false;" so he probably doesn't need e.prevent default, but yes i think you're right